# Mongodb with queries in JSON format

Tags: mongodb, bson

I was trying to solve a query given in an assessment to fetch details from a collection. The assessment was in online editor so I had to follow the base query structure.
MONGODB version 4.4

The base query was looking like below.

```
{
find : "MY_COLLECTION_1"
}
```

The collection name is "MY_COLLECTION_1", and there is field "FirstName" column in the collections like below.

```
{

{

"FirstName": "ABC"
}
{

"FirstName": "XYZ"
}
}
```

I have never seen the below format to fetch the data. Need help with this.

```
{
find : "MY_COLLECTION_1"
}
```

I tried to fetch something like below.

```
{
"find" : "MY_COLLECTION_1",
"FirstName" : "ABC"
}
```

but it's saying invalid BSON format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "online editor" appears to be using the [find database command](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/command/find/), which has the basic structure:

```
{
      find: <string>,
      filter: <document>,
      sort: <document>,
      projection: <document>,
      hint: <document or string>
}
```

You will likely need to use the `filter` field to pass in a query.